# Android- Create a list with names of all image folders only

Tags: android

I am stuck at a point where my activity generates a list containing an thumb image and name of all folders that contain images from SD card..
1. How do i filter only those folders with the images?
2. How do i get the thumb images from the first image in the folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
How do i filter only those folders with the images
```

you can check the extension of the files in the folder to see if they're of image type.

```
How do i get the thumb images from the first image in the folder
```

compress the file into smaller dimensions by using the following

```
public Bitmap compressBitmap(String filePath, int requiredSize)
{
    File file = new File(filePath);
    if (file.exists())
    {
        try
        {

            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);

            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = requiredSize;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true)
            {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                {
                    break;
                }
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, o2);
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    return null;
}
```